# setsockopt SO_SNDBUF and its behavior in unix domain

Tags: c, linux, sockets, unix-socket

I have a test unix domain server which has the following SO_SNDBUF is set to 1024000
while connection come in :

```
for ( ; ; ) {
    connfd = accept(fdfromps, 0, 0);

    int new_size = 1024000 ;
    setsockopt(connfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDBUF , &new_size, sizeof(new_size));

    SetSocketBlockingEnabled(connfd,false) ;
    FDArray[connfd] = 1 ;
} //for
```

also set this fd  to be nonblocking

The client won't recv any package what server send to client , so I 
can measure the counters while server send encounter error(errno=11) ,
the source is as the following :

Test1 :

```
strcpy(msg,"1234567890");
```

Test2 :

```
sprintf(msg,"%s%s%s%s%s",
"1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890",
"1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890",
"1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890",
"1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890",
"1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890") ;
```

and the test code :

```
sprintf(strsend,"%04d%s",strlen(msg),msg) ;
int icnt = 0 ;
pthread_detach(pthread_self());
while( 1 ){
    for(int idx=0;idx<20;idx++){
        if( FDArray[idx] == 1 ){
            int nread = send(idx,strsend,strlen(strsend),MSG_NOSIGNAL);
            if( nread < 0 ){
                printf("send to (%d) ...errno=(%d) \n",idx,errno );
                FDArray[idx] = 0 ;
            }else{
                printf("send to (%d) ... nread=(%d) \n", idx ,nread ) ;
                ++icnt ;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("......(%d) \n",icnt) ;
    usleep( 10000 ) ;
}
```

Test1 which msg has 14 bytes , the icnt is 2667 , Test2 which msg has 504 bytes,
the icnt is 1600 .

I am confused by the number 2667 and 1600 ,  since 504 bytes are much more than
14 bytes , I expect icnt of Test2 should be much bigger than icnt in Test1 ,
anything can explain that ?!

Env :

`sysctl -a | grep "mem"`:

```
net.core.rmem_default = 212992
net.core.rmem_max = 1024000
net.core.wmem_default = 212992
net.core.wmem_max = 1024000
```

`uname -a`:

```
3.10.0-327.el7.x86_64
```

Edit :

```
    int res = 0 ;
    optlen = sizeof(sendbuff);
    getsockopt(connfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDBUF , &sendbuff, &optlen);
    if(res == -1)
        printf("Error getsockopt one");
     else
         printf("send buffer size = %d\n", sendbuff);

    int new_size = 512000 ;
    setsockopt(connfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDBUF , &new_size, sizeof(new_size));
    getsockopt(connfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDBUF , &sendbuff, &optlen);
    if(res == -1)
        printf("Error getsockopt one");
     else
         printf("send buffer size = %d\n", sendbuff);
```

Edit 2 :

```
ss -ax | grep "testud"  ## testud  is the nnix domain name
```

will show  while Send-Q   is around 1024000 , the nonblocking send get errno =11
ever since ,  that  is what I observed and don't know would it help .

Answer (score 0):

The kernel can adjust the SO_SNDBUF value, up or down. Try getting it with `getsockopt()` after you set it, to see what it actually is.

Comment: thanks ,  before setsockopt  will be 212992 , after setsockopt will be 1024000 , means  setsockopt  work as expected , but its behavior still be strange . I have added Edit  in my question .